# ViewPager.PageTransformer Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to do the following,

Create grid of images using GridLayout inside a ScrollVIew inside a ViewPager, let's say I have pages of pictures, page 1 is animals, page2 plants, etc. And I want to be able to scroll up and down to view the images, of animals on page 1, and scroll right and left to change the page with an animation using PageTransformer. and I also need to see the pages on the left and the right as described [here](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1). Now I done all that but there is a conflict in the touch events that I can't resolve and this is where I need you help.

Now when I use  `pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());` I lose the the ScrollView up and down scroll and I get cool animation. And when I don't use it I get everything I need except the animation, How can I get them all?

This is my main activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    PagerContainer mContainer;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

        final ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
        PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
//Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
// make this at least however many pages you can see
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
//A little space between pages
        pager.setPageMargin(20);

//If hardware acceleration is enabled, you should also remove
// clipping on the pager for its children.
         pager.setClipChildren(false);
         pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

    }

    //Nothing special about this adapter, just throwing up colored views for demo
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(container.getContext());
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ScrollView sv=new ScrollView(container.getContext());

            GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(container.getContext());
            gl.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams ( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            gl.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            gl.setColumnCount(3);
            gl.setRowCount(3);

            for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
                ImageView imgView = new ImageView(container.getContext());
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                gl.addView( imgView);
            }

            sv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

            sv.addView(gl);
            container.addView(sv);


            return sv;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View)object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == object);
        }
    }
}
```

My page transformer is this,

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA);
            view.setScaleX(MIN_SCALE);
            view.setScaleY(MIN_SCALE);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +  (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));
            view.clearAnimation();

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA);
            view.setScaleX(MIN_SCALE);
            view.setScaleY(MIN_SCALE);

        }
    }
}
```

and finally my page container is this,

```
public class PagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;

    public PagerContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
//Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

//Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
//You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
// application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        try {
            mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
        }
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mPager;
    }

    private Point mCenter = new Point();
    private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mCenter.x = w / 2;
        mCenter.y = h / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
//We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
// to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouch.x = (int)ev.getX();
                mInitialTouch.y = (int)ev.getY();
            default:
                ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
                break;
        }

        return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
//Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
//Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static
        if (mNeedsRedraw) invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after looking at [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/4ccc001f3f883190ac8d900c4f69d71fda94690e/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java), the idea I that you don't need to use this  `pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());`, and copy some stuff from the link I mentioned earlier, and put `ZoomOutPageTransformer` as a function in your container as you will do the transformation inside it, the final code is below.

```
public class PagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;
    public PagerContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
//Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

//Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
//You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
// application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        try {
            mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
        }
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mPager;
    }

    private Point mCenter = new Point();
    private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mCenter.x = w / 2;
        mCenter.y = h / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
//We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
// to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouch.x = (int)ev.getX();
                mInitialTouch.y = (int)ev.getY();
            default:
                ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
                break;
        }

        return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
//Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
//Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static

        final int scrollX = mPager.getScrollX();
        final int childCount = mPager.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = mPager.getChildAt(i);
            final ViewPager.LayoutParams lp = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            if (lp.isDecor) continue;
            final float transformPos = (float) (child.getLeft() - scrollX) / child.getWidth();
            transformPage(child, transformPos);
        }
        if (mNeedsRedraw) invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//         mPager. getChildAt(3).setAlpha(05f);

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);

    }


    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
//            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA);
            view.setScaleX(MIN_SCALE);
            view.setScaleY(MIN_SCALE);


        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
//            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +  (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));
            view.clearAnimation();

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
//            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA);
            view.setScaleX(MIN_SCALE);
            view.setScaleY(MIN_SCALE);

        }
    }

}
```

Use only the PagerContainer and the MainActivity above and don't forger to disable setPageTransformer on it and that's it.